# How can I configure Sitecore so that it generates absolute links to media items?

Tags: performance, url, sitecore, pagespeed

`<sc:Image>` and `<sc:FieldRenderer>`, when rendering a MediaItem, generate html code that looks like the following:

```
<img src="~/media/twitter.gif" alt="Twitter" width="100" height="22" />
```

Notice the relative path used in `src` attribute: this means that when such an image is reused on multiple pages, the browser has to fetch it multiple times (e.g. on page http://example.com/ and http://example.com/about-us/). When I generate the `img` tag in code, I can use the following snippet to force an absolute URL:

```
string url = Sitecore.StringUtil.EnsurePrefix('/',
    Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(media));
```

How can I configure Sitecore to force the leading slash in media urls?

Using Reflector I can see that `MediaOptions.AbsolutePath` controls the behaviour that I want to achieve, but I don't know how can I set it for Sitecore built-in controls. Setting `Media.MediaLinkPrefix` or `mediaPrefixes` in `web.config` doesn't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I worked on a project where we stored media assets on Akamai's CDN, so we had to change how the media URLs resolved.

We adapted the built-in `LinkProvider` class by changing `ExpandDynamicLinks()`. We also adapted `Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaProvider` and updated the `GetMediaUrl()` method.

These were to handle links to images generated by field renderers and links created within a Rich Text editor.

Comment: That's the way we have solved this currently, but I was hoping for a configuration solution - Reflector shows that Sitecore is able to do this, I just don't know how to enable it. But if no configuration answer shows up, I'll accept yours.

Comment: I agree -- I would LOVE to see a config solution to this but I don't think there is one. * Fingers crossed *

Comment: I haven't found a config solution either. The last 2 sites I worked on used a CDN to serve media items and we had to do something very similar.

Comment: This would be a great opportunity to create a shared source module with these new classes and then a config file to patch the default settings.

Comment: We got response back from Sitecore - this is the solution they themselves are suggesting.

Answer (score 3):

There's a much easier solution to this. I may be a little off with my syntax - please feel free to correct me and I'll make edits.

```
MediaManager.GetItemUrl(item, new MediaUrlOptions { AbsolutePath = true });
```

Comment: The correct syntax is `MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(item, new MediaUrlOptions { AbsolutePath = true });`

Answer (score 0):

[**Create a Link to Sitecore Media Item**](http://itsmycode.com/create-link-to-sitecore-item-programmatically-using-link-manager/)

You will not be able to fetch the Media Item using the above LinkManager.GetItemUrl() Method. Sitecore has a separate API to fetch the Media URLs.

```
public string ResolveSitecoreMediaURL(Sitecore.Data.Items.Item item)
{
   MediaUrlOptions mediaOptions= new MediaUrlOptions();
   mediaOptions.AlwaysIncludeServerUrl = true;
   mediaOptions.AbsolutePath =true;
   return Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(item,mediaOptions);
}
```

Like LinkManager had the URLOptions MediaManager comes with a MediaUrlOptions where you can control the absolute and relative URLs.