# Get media url including server part

Tags: c#, sitecore

Is it possible to get url with `MediaManager.GetMediaUrl` that always includes the server part?

Answer (score 9):

Just to bump this up, in Sitecore 7 the `AlwaysIncludeServerUrl` option is also included in `MediaUrlOptions` (I don't know since which version of Sitecore)

Like this:

```cs
MediaUrlOptions muo = new MediaUrlOptions();
muo.AlwaysIncludeServerUrl = true;
String url = MediaManager.GetMediaUrl((MediaItem)item, muo);
```

Answer (score 3):

I've discovered that the following will work for producing fully qualified urls for media items:

```cs
public static string GetMediaUrlWithServer(MediaItem mediaItem, Item item = null)
{
    item = item ?? Sitecore.Context.Item;
    var options = new UrlOptions {AlwaysIncludeServerUrl = true, AddAspxExtension = false};
    var itemUrl = LinkManager.GetItemUrl(item, options);
    var mediaOptions = new MediaUrlOptions {AbsolutePath = true};
    var mediaUrl = MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(mediaItem, mediaOptions);
    return itemUrl + mediaUrl;
}
```

The urls produced will be relative to `item` so you may want to supply a reference to your Home item instead of `Sitecore.Context.Item`

Answer (score 0):

I just answered [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977809/how-can-i-configure-sitecore-so-that-it-generates-absolute-links-to-media-items/5982547#5982547) on Stack Overflow recently. I believe the answer applies to yours as well.

Short summary: there is no configuration to do this, you need to override some of the built-in methods to do this. See the above link for the exact details.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that!

The correct way of setting this parameter is specifying within config file at **linkManager** section, where you have this anв the rest of settings regarding how you URLs will be resolved. Here's the whole section, you're interested in **alwaysIncludeServerUrl** parameter:

```xml
<linkManager defaultProvider="sitecore">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="sitecore" type="Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider, Sitecore.Kernel"
         alwaysIncludeServerUrl="true"             
         addAspxExtension="true"
         encodeNames="true"
         languageEmbedding="asNeeded"
         languageLocation="filePath"
         shortenUrls="true"
         useDisplayName="false" />
  </providers>
</linkManager>
```

Comment: Don't think this applies to MediaManager.GetMediaUrl