# Suggestions for testing Sitecore 301 URL Redirect

Tags: redirect, sitecore, http-status-code-301, sitecore6, sitecore-azure

We are using a sitecore 301 URL redirect module for our large scale sitecore project below:
https://github.com/thecadams/301RedirectModule

The solution is being hosted in ms azure. We need to
test to make sure that all the pages that's been renamed from old domain in to sitecore item should be redirected to new URL using 301 permanent redirect. This way google's index
gets updated as well.

Any one's suggestion will be appreciated:

1. The CName for old domain has not been updated yet to new url. How do we perform 301 redirect test in such scenario.
2. There are more than one old domain (eg. A.COM,B.COM) which we are migrating to one domain (e.g A.COM), of which we will be using one old domain CName to point to new URL. How do we test the one (e.g. B.COM) which will be shut down? Does this 301 Redirect module support such scenario?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. That's what Test and QA servers are for. Can you create a subdomain (test.domain.com) to  test this? You should set up some automated tests to check this, as well as plain old manual testing, to allow you to make this test repeatable using something like [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/).

   You could always set up a `hosts` file entry on your local machine:

   ```
   127.0.0.1   a.com
   127.0.0.1   b.com
   ```

   Don't forget to add these bindings to IIS also.
2. Not sure, but that module supports RegEx. If the host name part is ignored by the regex then download the source and modify to meet your requirements, i.e. if current domain is not A.COM then redirect to A.COM/somepage.

You can set the `hostName` and `targetHostName` in `web.config <sites>` section to catch both domains:

`<site name="website" hostName="a.com|b.com" tagetHostName="a.com" ... />`

> hostName: The host name of the incoming url. May include wildcards (ex. www.site.net, *.site.net, *.net, pda.*, print.*.net)
>   It's possible to set more than one mask by using '|' symbol as a separator (ex. pda.*|print.*.net)

And then update the Redirect Module code always include the server URL in the return:

`return LinkManager.GetItemUrl(redirectToItem, new UrlOptions() { AlwaysIncludeServerUrl = true });`

If you need to redirect media items then take a looks at [Get media url including server part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122901/get-media-url-including-server-part) and update the code as appropriate.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to explore and provide suggestions.appreciate it.