# Akamai CDN integration with Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, akamai

For our website, we want to use Akamai as CDN. The problem we have intercept all the html and change media URL's to akamai URL's.

for eg:
~/media/Marketing/Stages/EmailMarkeImg.ashx

http://media.akamai.com/~/Marketing/Stages/EmailMarkeImg.ashx

So, right now, i am intercepting this using Response filters in a HttpModule. But there are performance issues with this, reason is, we need to find out all the tags with ~/media and append that name :http://media.akamai.com before all the 
This is really a performance issue from the response point of view.

This is my first sitecore project and i am trying get a deep insight into this. But, i know you guys must have already done these kind of things. Please help me in this case.

PS: Any options of extending the pipe lines, when the current item  is looking for a media library image, just appending the akamai domain path.

Please let me know.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

If you are running 6.4 or later you can use the setting Media.MediaLinkPrefix.

Example patch:

http://cdn.mydomain.net/~/media/

This works only for media items in the media library.

Answer (score 3):

I've answered this before:

[How can I configure Sitecore so that it generates absolute links to media items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977809/how-can-i-configure-sitecore-so-that-it-generates-absolute-links-to-media-items/5982547)

Short summary: there is no configuration to do this, you need to override some of the built-in methods to do this. See the above link for the exact details.