# how to change the media url in sitecore?

Tags: sitecore

I am working on a project using sitecore6.5 where we store media assets on Akamai's CDN, so we have to change how the media URLs resolved.The thread below is exactly what i'm looking for,
it looks like i need to make some changes on

> LinkProvider class's ExpandDynamicLinks() and Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaProvider's GetMediaUrl() method.

Could anyone tell me something in more detail, show some sample code,if possible!
Thanks !

[How can I configure Sitecore so that it generates absolute links to media items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977809/how-can-i-configure-sitecore-so-that-it-generates-absolute-links-to-media-items)

Answer (score 2):

Make a per environment patch file like so:

```
  <setting name="Media.MediaLinkPrefix">
      <patch:attribute name="value">http://mycdn.mydomain.com/~/media</patch:attribute>
  </setting>
```

Or just do the change directly in web.config, depending on your preferences.

Comment: Thanks so much, pbering, I've done that. it does change the url. but i'd like to add some logic to override the methods of the linkProvider and mediaProvider which i haven't figure it out yet.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this blog post as it provides additional sample code: [Using Akamai Net Storage for Sitecore Media Items](http://www.sitecoredevelopment.com/en/MarkGraber/2011/January/Using-Akamai-Net-Storage-for-Sitecore-Media-Items.aspx)

Also, as the post you refer to says (which I answered), you should decompile the out-of-the-box classes I reference and adjust them. You can use something like [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx) to decompile them for free. I would implement them as-is in a custom class and just get that to work, then you can debug them and see where you need to make adjustments.

Comment: "Using Akamai..." link is broken.

Comment: http://www.sitecoredevelopment.com/en/MarkGraber/2011/January/Using-Akamai-Net-Storage-for-Sitecore-Media-Items.aspx