# How to get all media items in sitecore?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-media-library

I'm adding a pipeline into the sitecore. what i'm trying to do is get all the media items, and change the url as we will put all the media assets into a CDN. and, the problem is simple, How to get the all the media items? anyone knows?

Comment: I don't understand why you're trying to get all media items in a pipeline? Why wouldn't you have the pipeline processor alter the URL for the given item being requested?

Comment: Thanks for your tip, i really should have. The ultimate goal is be able to switch the url of the media item by add a checkbox field to the image base template. The problem is how to change the url of the media item.

Comment: I've previously answered a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977809/how-can-i-configure-sitecore-so-that-it-generates-absolute-links-to-media-items/5982547

Answer (score 2):

In your custom assembly do something like this:

```
Sitecore.Data.Items.Item home = db.GetItem("/sitecore/media library");
using (new Sitecore.SecurityModel.SecurityDisabler())
    {
        alterItem(home);
    }

protected void alterItem(Sitecore.Data.Items.Item root)
{       

    foreach (Sitecore.Data.Items.Item itm in root.Children)
    {        

      //follow "absolute url" example below and edit each media item as you enumerate

      //Use recursion to loop through the entire tree under the root item
      alterItem(itm);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But there is no such field which represents the url of the media item, and no such template used by the url of the media item.

Comment: check this out..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977809/how-can-i-configure-sitecore-so-that-it-generates-absolute-links-to-media-items/5982547

Comment: by the way a neater way to get the media library root is Sitecore.ItemIDs.MediaLibraryRoot

Answer (score 0):

You cannot walk the Sitecore media library tree and change URLs of items. The main reason is that a `MediaItem` (or any `Item` for that matter) doesn't have a property for `URL`. The URL that points to an item is determined by many configuration settings (the site the item is in, link prefixes, current language, 'file' extensions, etc...).

Being that there are many factors that control the actual URL of an item there are a few methods that you leverage to get the URL of an item at **render time**. The methods you should be using to get a URL to an item would be:

- `Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetItemUrl()`
- `Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl()`

You can do something that foxtrotZulu is suggesting. Essentially, add your own field to each `MediaItem` that stores the URL to the item on the CDN. You would need to either manually, or programtically, set the value of your custom URL field for each media item. Then, at **render time** you would use that field value rather than a call to the `MediaManager`.

You may also want to look at leveraging various configuration settings to control the URL returned via a call to `Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl()`